# How to setup a CakePHP Cron / Shell task on MacOSX?

Tags: php, macos, shell, cakephp, cron

I have a cakephp shell that works correctly. If I run

```
/Users/petarpetrov/path_to/app/Console/cake CleanDatabase
```

it works great. However, as per [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) if I try this:

```
  * * * * * cd /Users/petarpetrov/path_to/app && Console/cake CleanDatabase
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: Config: command not found
```

I noticed that it does matter where I am at the point of issuing the crontab command. If I run it from `/` I would get:

```
-bash: Applications: command not found
```

So I have really no idea what is going on. Any help?

Task code:

```
<?php
class CleanDatabaseShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        $this->out('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide source code of CleanDatabase task? cake script `https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Console/cake` did not contains  `Config`, `Applications` as your crontab configuration. So, seems it's something in CleanDatabase definition

Comment: sure, I updated the question to include the simplistic task code

Comment: so, you mean that it execution produce same errors?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was pasting this line in terminal which was wrong:

```
  * * * * * cd /Users/petarpetrov/path_to/app && Console/cake CleanDatabase
```

when in fact I should have done:

1. `crontab -e` to open the editor
2. paste the line in
3. save & close it.